# Append in jquery executes function while appending

Tags: jquery

The following code

```
       $("#main").append("<img onmouseover="+mouseOver()+" 
       onmouseout="+mouseOut()+" src="+result[i].image+">")
```

Executes the onmouseover and onmouseout function when the .append function happens. I want it instead to execute only when the onmouseover/out occurs. Which does not happen. How do I 'echo' it into the HTML without executing it upon .append?

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the functions as text, like this:

```
$("#main").append('<img onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" src='+result[i].image+'>')
```

otherwise you are executing the function while appending it to `#main`

Comment: You're right.. it seems correct to me, I tried that, but then the code editor does not highlight the function in blue  : ( nor does it actually execute it.

Comment: Mmm, it's fine if the editor doesn't highlight it as it is just mere text, and the browser will recognize it as JS code. It has to be executed, check your code if by the time you are appending them your functions already exist